# List all AWS Elasticache snapshots taken after a specified date

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-elasticache, jmespath

I am trying to write a query in AWS CLI which will provide with the elasticache snapshots names older than a specific creation date.

I tried with a JMESPath query like:

```bash
aws elasticache describe-snapshots \
  --region ap-southeast-1 \
  --snapshot-source "manual" \
  --query 'Snapshots[*].NodeSnapshots[?SnapshotCreateTime >`2022-10-01`] | [?not_null(node)]'
```

But, this is giving me an empty result.

Snippet of `aws elasticache describe-snapshots`:

```json
{
    "Snapshots": [{
        "SnapshotName": "snapshot-name",
        "ReplicationGroupId": "rep-id",
        "ReplicationGroupDescription": "redis  cluster",
        "CacheClusterId": null,
        "SnapshotStatus": "available",
        "SnapshotSource": "automated",
        "CacheNodeType": "cache.r6g.large",
        "Engine": "redis",
        "EngineVersion": "6.0.5",
        "NumCacheNodes": null,
        "PreferredAvailabilityZone": null,
        "CacheClusterCreateTime": null,
        "PreferredMaintenanceWindow": "sun:20:00-sun:20:00",
        "TopicArn": null,
        "Port": "6379",
        "CacheParameterGroupName": "default.redis6.x.cluster.on",
        "CacheSubnetGroupName": "redis-group",
        "VpcId": "vpc-01bcajghfghj",
        "AutoMinorVersionUpgrade": "true",
        "SnapshotRetentionLimit": "18",
        "SnapshotWindow": "20:00-21:00",
        "NumNodeGroups": "1",
        "AutomaticFailover": "enabled",
        "NodeSnapshots": [{
            "CacheClusterId": "redis-cluster-01",
            "NodeGroupId": "001",
            "CacheNodeId": "001",
            "NodeGroupConfiguration": null,
            "CacheSize": "20 GB",
            "CacheNodeCreateTime": "1632909889675",
            "SnapshotCreateTime": "1667246439000"
        }],
        "KmsKeyId": "kms-id.."
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If we take as an example the JSON given [in the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elasticache/describe-snapshots.html#examples):

```json
{
    "Snapshots": [
        {
            "SnapshotName": "automatic.my-cluster2-002-2019-12-05-06-38",
            "NodeSnapshots": [
                {
                    "CacheNodeId": "0001",
                    "SnapshotCreateTime": "2019-12-05T06:38:23Z"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "SnapshotName": "myreplica-backup",
            "NodeSnapshots": [
                {
                    "CacheNodeId": "0001",
                    "SnapshotCreateTime": "2019-11-26T00:25:01Z"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "SnapshotName": "my-cluster",
            "NodeSnapshots": [
                {
                    "CacheNodeId": "0001",
                    "SnapshotCreateTime": "2019-11-26T03:08:33Z"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Then, you can realise that you need to filter on `SnapshotCreateTime`, nested under the array `NodeSnapshots`.

So, what you need, here, is a double filter:

- One to filter by date:

  ```
  [?SnapshotCreateTime > `2022-10-01`]
  ```
- Then, one to exclude all snapshots where the `NodeSnapshots` array has been emptied by the previous filter:

  ```
  [?NodeSnapshots[?SnapshotCreateTime > `2022-10-01`]]
  ```

And, so, if you only care about the name of the snapshot, you could do with the query:

```
Snapshots[?NodeSnapshots[?SnapshotCreateTime > `2022-10-01`]].SnapshotName
```

So, your command ends up being:

```bash
aws elasticache describe-snapshots \
  --region ap-southeast-1 \
  --snapshot-source "manual" \
  --query 'Snapshots[?
      NodeSnapshots[?SnapshotCreateTime > `2022-10-01`]
    ].SnapshotName'
```

---

Now, with what you are showing as an output in your question, your issue is also coming from the fact that your `SnapshotCreateTime` is in [epoch format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) in liliseconds, so you just have to convert `2022-10-01` in the right format.

If you are on Linux, you can do this within your command, with `date`:

```bash
aws elasticache describe-snapshots \
  --region ap-southeast-1 \
  --snapshot-source "manual" \
  --query "Snapshots[?
      NodeSnapshots[?
        SnapshotCreateTime > \`$(date --date='2022-10-01' +'%s')000\`
      ]
    ].SnapshotName"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried using the above mentioned command but its not filtering the snapshots by the date mentioned. Its still showing blank after running the query but I have snapshots present after the mentioned date.

Comment: I assume the issue is with the filtering of dates as JSON does not have a built-in type for date/time values. The general consensus is to store the date/time value as a string . Please help with the possible solutions..

Comment: JSON doesn't indeed have a date or date time type. This said, the good thing with the string représentation used here is that is works as string too: `"2022-10-01" > "2022-10-05"` is true. You could try to do ```NodeSnapshots[?SnapshotCreateTime > `2022-10-01T00:00:00Z` ``` to be extra sure, but this should work.

Comment: In order to help you further, you should provide, in an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74430857/edit) of your question, an anonymised JSON output of the `aws elasticache describe-snapshots` command without any query.

Comment: I have updated the question with a JSON output.

Comment: I have tried doing `NodeSnapshots[?SnapshotCreateTime > 2022-10-01T00:00:00Z` but its still showing blank